# Filtering by Favorite Tag including wildcard ("*") and related tag does not filter

Tags: bug, status-declined, tags, tag-watching, related-tags

I have a favorite Tag including a wildcard [[wpf*]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wpf*) in my **Favorite Tags** list to get all question tagged with wpf. (Currently 63,210 question)

Now when i click on a Related Tag, such as [[c#]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wpf+or+wpf-controls+or+wpfdatagrid+or+wpftoolkit+or+wpf-4.0+or+wpf-4.5+c#) (the count behind the tag states that there are 26,324 question), the c#-Tag gets ignored and the result is still all the 63,210 questions.

The result of the tag-filtering above, should be equal to the search [[wpf*] [c#] is:question](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bwpf*%5D+%5Bc%23%5D+is%3Aq)

Comment: I think the issue is not only with favorite tags but also with any tags including a wildcard.

Comment: @hims056 yes indeed

Answer (score 2):

It looks like what is happening is that the "and" is implicit with the last tag only; for example, the link for clicking on [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23) is:

```
<a href="/questions/tagged/wpf+or+wpf-controls+or+wpfdatagrid+or+wpftoolkit+or+wpf-4.0+or+wpf-positioning+or+wpf-4.5+or+wpf-animation+or+wpf-interop+or+wpf-brushes+c%23" class="post-tag js-gps-track" title="" rel="tag">c#</a>
```

so the "and" is binding only to [wpf-brushes](/questions/tagged/wpf-brushes) and [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23). The query-string does not currently support arbitrary combinations of "and" and "or"... I can't think of a nice way of expressing this, to be honest.

Comment: What about parentheses? `(wpf or wpf-controls) and c#`

Comment: @michaelb958 oddly enough, the backend "list stuff by tag" can cope with that, but that would involve a *significant* amount of change to the UI code; otherwise I'd have already done it ;p

Answer (score 1):

A workaround to get the results for [wpf*] and the related tag [c#] is by using the search engine of SO

[[wpf*][c#] is:question](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bwpf*%5D%20%5Bc#%5D%20is:q)