# How do I search for [tag1] and [tag2-*]?

Tags: discussion, bug, tags, search, elasticsearch

When trying to search for `[tag1] [tag2-*]` (logically `[tag1] and [tag2-*]` since default is AND) the search query gets turned into `[tag2-a] or [tag2-b] or [tag2-c] ... or [tag2-z] and  [tag1]` which is not what I intended to search for.

This is equivalent to `[tag2-a] or [tag2-b] or [tag2-c] ... or ([tag2-z] and  [tag1])`.

So, how do I search for `([tag1] and [tag2-a]) or ([tag1] and [tag2-b]) or ..... or ([tag1] and [tag2-z])`?

Example : I wanted to search for all [feature-requests](/questions/tagged/feature-requests) which have any of the status tags. So I tried this, [[feature-request] [status-*]](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/status-completed+or+status-bydesign+or+status-declined+or+status-norepro+or+status-deferred+or+status-planned+or+status-review+or+status-reproduced+feature-request) However, I ended up with all posts ([bug](/questions/tagged/bug), [support](/questions/tagged/support)) which have any of the status tags and only [status-reproduced](/questions/tagged/status-reproduced) (which happened to be the last status tag in the query) with [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)

Comment: `[tag3-c]`? Don't you mean `[tag2-c]`?

Comment: A concrete example, with links to the search results with what you've tried may help people understand. I think you mean you can search for [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/status-completed+or+status-bydesign+or+status-declined+or+status-norepro+or+status-deferred+or+status-planned+or+status-review+or+status-reproduced+feature-request) by searching for `[feature-request] [status-*]` but I don't know what you are trying to search for with the second half...

Comment: @jmac Does it make sense now?

Comment: ah, yes, that makes much more sense. So the issue is that you want to search for `[feature-request] AND [status-*]` but are getting search language that reads `[feature-request] OR [status-*]`. This is an interest conundrum, wish I knew the answer!

Answer (score 1):

There is a way round. Include the parameter `is:question` in your search query and you will get the required results.

[[feature-request][status-*] is:question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bfeature-request%5D%5Bstatus-*%5D%20is:q)

I noticed the behavior once before and opened the post [Filtering by Favorite Tag including wildcard ("*") and related tag does not filter](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/176554/filtering-by-favorite-tag-including-wildcard-and-related-tag-does-not-filter) here on meta. It is the exact same problem as you described.